# Azure Data Factory v2 fails at sending data to Azure Search

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to transfer some data to Azure Search, but for some reason it fails with `Invalid linked service reference. Name: AzureSearch1`

I have set up an Azure Search Linked Service like this:

```
{
"name": "AzureSearch1",
"properties": {
    "type": "AzureSearch",
    "typeProperties": {
        "url": "https://xxxxxx.search.windows.net",
        "key": {
            "type": "AzureKeyVaultSecret",
            "store": {
                "referenceName": "AzureKeyVault",
                "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
            },
            "secretName": "Search-AdminKey"
        }
    },
    "connectVia": {
        "referenceName": "integrationRuntime1",
        "type": "IntegrationRuntimeReference"
    }
}
}
```

"Test connection" works fine.

Now, I'm trying to create an Azure Search Indexer like this:

```
{
    "name": "AzureSearchIndex_PriceSheet",
    "properties": {
        "linkedServiceName": {
            "referenceName": "AzureSearch1",
            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
        },
        "type": "AzureSearchIndex",
        "typeProperties": {
            "indexName": "pricesheet"
        }
    }
}
```

but it fails when I click "Preview Data" or "Import Schema" with this error:
`Invalid linked service reference. Name: AzureSearch1. Activity ID:2fa29fe9-ca5d-4308-af62-xxxxxxxxx`

The integration pipeline is set to "West Europe" and Azure Search in provisioned in that region too.

Any thoughts?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your issue but failed.Please refer to my working configuration:

My Azure Search Linked Service:

```
{
    "name": "AzureSearch1",
    "properties": {
        "type": "AzureSearch",
        "typeProperties": {
            "url": "https://***.search.windows.net",
            "key": {
                "type": "AzureKeyVaultSecret",
                "store": {
                    "referenceName": "AzureKeyVault1",
                    "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                },
                "secretName": "testas"
            }
        }
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedservices"
}
```

My Azure Search Indexer:

```
{
    "name": "AzureSearchIndex1",
    "properties": {
        "linkedServiceName": {
            "referenceName": "AzureSearch1",
            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
        },
        "folder": {
            "name": "azureSearch"
        },
        "type": "AzureSearchIndex",
        "typeProperties": {
            "indexName": "documentdb-index"
        }
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/datasets"
}
```

***Perview Data:***

[image]

I presumed it may because the secret which is stored in AKV has expired,then the link lost connection.I suggest you re-creating secret in AKV(just set default configuration) and try again.

Hope it helps you.Any concern,let me know.

Comment: I took out the KeyVault part and just hard-coded the key and that worked. So, I dived into the KeyVault and there was an issue with the MSI permissions and that fixed it. Thanks!